# How to create asp.net web application using sqlite

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, visual-studio-2010, sqlite

I want to develop small application in asp.net using sqlite, actually I don't know how to use sqlite in application. Can anybody provide a link for step by step process to create a application in asp.net code behind c#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This guide should get you started:

[Using SQLite in your C# Application](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SQLiteCSharp.aspx)

Ultimately using SQLite is very similar to using Microsoft SQL Server, just with different objects and an extra assembly reference.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for giving response i have to try to develop a small application i have a small doubt where i can write a code for creating tables in sqlite window application. please help me.....

Comment: @Victor You can download the command line shell tool SQLite3.exe from the [SQLite website](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) that allows you to create a datbase and execute commands against it (e.g.`CREATE TABLE`). There are also GUI tools for SQLite database management - try google searching for these (I use SQLite3.exe myself).

Comment: Ok thank you so much actually i don't know i to use sqlite in asp.net..

Comment: You should first learn basic asp.net then go on to sqlite
https://asp.mvc-tutorial.com/

Answer (score 9):

You create it the same way you would any regular asp.net web application - You probably want to use a provider for it, such as this: http://system.data.sqlite.org/

Here is how to make the connection: http://www.fryan0911.com/2009/10/c-how-to-connect-to-sqlite-database.html

More information about sqlite functionality here: http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Database/Using-SQLite-for-Simple-Database-Storage/

There are certain subtleties that is different than regular sql server - you can read about it on that site. Here is another question that has some information on these subtle differences: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822548/c-sqlite-syntax-in-asp-net

Comment: Thank you to all,i have try to create appliction but showing error like  File 'C:\Documents and Settings\stellent\Desktop\sqlitebrowser_200_b1_win\Source\SQLLite\SQLLite\bin\Debug\DemoT.db' does not exist. Use ConnectionString parameter New=True to create new file

Comment: Hi,where i write the code to create the tables please tell me .....

Comment: Its in the second page of the article in the post: http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Database/Using-SQLite-for-Simple-Database-Storage/1/

Comment: Hi thank you to give a response ,i have a small issue how to create auto increment in sqlite for primary key...please tell me...

Comment: when you create the table definition, you can add INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT to the field. Read more about it here: http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: i have create as identity(1,1) for auto increment ... is it posible..

Comment: actually i have create the tables using Firefox sqlite manager ,in this AUTOINCREMENT not acepting its show the error.

Answer (score 2):

Use this for connect to sqlite

http://system.data.sqlite.org/

Answer (score 2):

Try to this code

```
public class DBhelperClass
{
    string dbConnection = "Data Source=ShyamDB.s3db";
    public DataTable GetDataTable(string sql) {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try {
            SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection);
            cnn.Open();
            SQLiteCommand mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(cnn);
            mycommand.CommandText = sql;
            SQLiteDataReader reader = mycommand.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(reader);
            reader.Close();
            cnn.Close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
    return dt;
    }
}

//string   nputFile = "ShyamDB.s3db" is mydb name ;
DBhelperClass db = new  DBhelperClass(); 
dataGridView1.DataSource = db.GetDataTable("Select * from ShyamTable");
```

Final result loads in `DataGridView`.