# Deploy Sqlite for asp.net

Tags: asp.net, system.data.sqlite

I'd like to deploy a Sqlite db as the back end of asp.net (vb) pages. It seems I need to put System.Data.Sqlite.dll on the web server.

Where does it go, and what set up needs to be done to use it?

Comment: When you build it(When you have added as reference to your web site), it automatically creates Bin folder and in it you have your Systm.Data.sqlite.dll. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Have a look at this previous answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813873/how-to-create-asp-net-web-application-using-sqlite

Comment: @Thomas From the referenced article: "Use the SQLite.NET.dll in your .NET application by ‘Project -> Add Reference’".It's the "add a reference" part that I don't know how to do. Is this using an IDE?