# Read Android database.db file from asp.net

Tags: android, asp.net, android-sqlite

i want to read Android database file from asp.net.

First i want to directly browse it locally

then want to just read data from it and display it in Grid view.

So how can i do that ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those *.db are just dtandard SQLite datases, which is a simple open source Database, there are libraries avilable for use with C# in .Net, see this question for examples: [How to create asp.net web application using sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813873/how-to-create-asp-net-web-application-using-sqlite)

Answer (score 0):

Android uses SQLite and its *.db files are regular SQLite database files. I am not familiar with asp.net but if you can use SQLite with it, then you can look for a way to use it with own db file. Mind, however, that you will not be able to get the SQLite database file from regular android device (unless it is rooted or you deal with emulator)