# How to query the session in ASP.NET MVC with a dynamic query

Tags: session, nosql, redis, ravendb, in-memory-database

I want to store some user data in memory, like some in-memory noSQL database.

But later on I want to query that data with a dynamic query constructed from the user. That query is stored in a classic DB like a string, so when I need to query the data stored in memory I would like to parse that string and construct the desired query (by some known rules).

I looked at Redis and I figured out it isn't maintained for Windows anymore, I have also looked at RavenDB but it's main query language is LINQ, even though it can be created dynamic Lucene Query.

Can you suggest me another in memory DB that work with ASP.NET and can be queried with a dynamically created query? Maybe I haven't seen all the options.

I prefer name-value or JSON based noSQL so it's schema can be easyly modified without the constraints of the relation type of DBs

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to simply use sqlite. It can be easily used as an in-memory database (just open the database using ":memory:" instead of a file name).

You can use a simple 2 columns table with a primary key to emulate a key/value store.

Here are a few links you might find helpful:

http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html

[How to create asp.net web application using sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813873/how-to-create-asp-net-web-application-using-sqlite)